# CSS <ul> - <li> menu: <a> element width height setting

Tags: html, css

[image]

I am trying to solve this issue for a few days now. I am unable to place the Child1, 2 and 3 between the 25px orange spot. The parent and child menu is a CSS based `ul` - `li` menu, where I set the `<a>` as an *inline-block* and set the width and height but it still ignores those parameters. I am out of ideas on how to solve this matter. Thank you for your help in advance.

Due to the length of the code I decided to upload the "whole" source code:
[source.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ucc56le4bf8y8vd/source.zip)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `<a>` tags on the sub-menu have the `padding:15px` from the main menu. You will need to set it to 0. You can then set the `line-height` of the element to match the orange bar's `height` to center it vertically.

Add this to fix it:

```
#header .cssMenuA a{
    padding:0;
    line-height:25px;
}
```

Comment: excellent! How did I not get this... thank you very much for your help! Very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the Child 1, 2, 3 `a` tags have padding applied to them, which is pushing them down past the orange. See screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Try removing the padding from the a tags (bodystyle.css, line 78), and reapplying it only to the parent menu items.

Comment: I didn't realize the padding comes from another element, thank you very much :)

Comment: Chrome developer tools are extremely useful :)

Answer (score 1):

You have 15px of padding around all of the `<a>` elements in the nav list (including `PARENT`), but this also applies to the "Childs."  Add the rule:

```
#header li li a {
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

This may not look exactly like you want because the `<a>` is set at 25px high, but the font is smaller than that.  Also add

```
#header li li a span {
    line-height: 25px;
}
```